# Accessing TextView from another class

Tags: android, view, textview

I've got my main startup class loading main.xml but I'm trying to figure out how to access the TextView from another class which is loading information from a database. I would like to publish that information to the TextView.

So far I've not found any helpful examples on Google.

EDIT:
This is my class that is doing the Database work:

```
import android.widget.TextView;import android.view.View; 
public class DBWork{
    private View view;
...
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
tv.setText("TEXT ME")
```

Yet, everytime I do that I get a nullpointerexception

Comment: How is your main class calling the DBWork class?

Comment: This is inside the onCreate:
new DBWork("http://192.168.2.14:8080/DH/DPost", "test_db");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I'd keep all your UI updates within your main `Activity` class.  You just get your `DBWork` class to return the text you want displayed to your `Activity`.  So something like:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        DBWork db = new DBWork("192.168.2.14:8080/DH/DPost";, "test_db");
        tv.setText(db.getText()); 
    }
}
```

Then your db class:

```
public class DBWork{
    ...
    public String getText(){
        //do stuff
        return "";
    }
}
```

Please note that any database operations you perform during `onCreate` should be as quick as possible as they are running in the UI thread.  If you are going to perform long running database queries then you should use an `AsyncTask` or create a new `Thread` and use a `Handler` to update the UI.

Answer (score 3):

You should use LayoutInflater :

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewInXml);
```

Comment: It's `myView.findViewById(..)`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the references to all your controls after you created your class instance. I personally pass the whole class that has all controls as public variables.

Answer (score 0):

You havew to define your TextView using xml and giving it an id. Example:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:textColor="#FFF"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                  android:paddingRight="5dip"
                  android:text="@string/name"
                  android:id="@+id/myTextViewInXml"/>
```

Then you cann access it in every class using

```
 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewInXml);
```

Comment: I think that `findViewById(int)` will only retrieve a UI element from a resource that you have already loaded using `setContentView(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's right:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewInXml);
```

But before you have to specify what file you want use by:

> setContentView(id of XML file which include R.id.myTextViewInXml)

Without that the   `findViewById(R.id.myTextViewInXml);` alway will return `null`.

This is an example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.virtualtour); // before !!
        progress_bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.vt_progress);
        loading_ly = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vt_layout_loading);
        panorama_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vt_description);
        virtualtour_relatively = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.vt_layout_opengl);

.........
```

Comment: I tried creating the onCreate in my class and turning my class into an activity, yet when I do label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01); label is still being found null.

Comment: The class must be an extension if an activity.For example public class miaSuocera extends Activity{......}.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView bt1 =m_activity.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

In the above example where view bt1 is from another class.you can access bt1 by using class instance and get the id.Now,do what ever you want do with bt1 instance.

Note: Make Sure bt1 is public in another class