# c# Android access textview from another class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm writing an android app in c#, which communicates with a server.

```
// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);  

Client client = new Client();
client.Setup("ws://192.168.0.14:8001", "basic", WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455);
client.Start();
...
```

On start up, it should display a message on the TextView.

```
class Client : Activity{
    private WebSocket websocketClient;
    ...
    public void Setup(string url, string protocol, WebSocketVersion version)
    {
    ...
    websocketClient.Opened += new EventHandler(websocketClient_Opened);
    }

    private void websocketClient_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e){
        txt.Text = ("Client successfully connected."); // this line is wrong
        websocketClient.Send("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The problem is, I have no idea, how to access the TextView. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608524/accessing-textview-from-another-class), but I don't know how should I use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just make WebsocketClient a property it a instead of a class variable and then you can access it from you activity.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private TextView txt;
    private Client client;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        client = new Client();
        client.WebsocketClient.Opened += websocketClient_Opened;
        client.Setup("ws://192.168.0.14:8001", "basic", WebSocketVersion.Rfc6455);
        client.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        client.WebsocketClient.Opened -= websocketClient_Opened;
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    private void websocketClient_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt.Text = ("Client successfully connected.");
        // maybe have to be wrapped in a RunOnUiThread(() =>{ ... });
    }
}

class Client
{
    public WebSocket WebsocketClient { get; set; }

    public void Setup(string url, string protocol, WebSocketVersion version)
    {
        // WebsocketClient = new  ...
        WebsocketClient.Opened += websocketClient_Opened;
    }

    private void websocketClient_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebsocketClient.Send("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library WebSocket you a using. I using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp). It is example use:

```
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
       TextView txt = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.My);

        using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://dragonsnest.far/Laputa"))
        {
            ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
            {
                txt.Text = e.Message;
            };
            ..........
        }
```

It is work. I see error message in my TextView.

If you get error, try use RunOnUiThread.Example:

```
    private void websocketClient_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
       this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    txt.Text = "your message";
                });        
    }
```

Hope this help.